# Oracle Endeca Sharepoint Web Services Data Source plugin

Tags: search, cas, endeca

I'm attempting to crawl a MS Sharepoint environment using a local Oracle Endeca instance (11.1.0). Per Oracle's documentation there should be a 'Sharepoint WebServices Data Source' option within the 'CAS Console' but it is not present.

The documentation goes into detail on configuring the data source, but provides no information on getting the plugin installed to begin with, or even if a plugin exists, it seems like this should be OOTB but it is nowhere to be found.

Appreciate any information on the subject from anyone who has successfully used this connector with Endeca before.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Sharepoint WebServices Data Source' requires a separate license, stay classy Oracle.